# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "¡qué pasada!"?

Tags: historia, expresiones

Con frecuencia en España se dice *¡qué pasada!* para referirse a algo excepcionalmente bueno e incluso sorprendente.

> Juan corrió la maratón en menos de tres horas, ¡qué pasada!
>
> La atracción es muy emocionante, ¡qué pasada!

Miro en la RAE
la definición de *pasada* y no encuentro nada que encaje bien

> [**pasado, da**](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?id=w3ewXKQMEDXX2B35332w%7CydPIscAM1DXX2s282U4Y)
>
> (Del part. de pasar).
>
> 1. adj. Cuba. Dicho de una persona: Muy inteligente.
> 2. adj. Cuba. Dicho de una cosa: De buena calidad.
> 3. adj. Cuba. Dicho de una mujer: Atractiva y de formas exuberantes.
> 4. m. Tiempo que pasó.
> 5. m. Cosas que sucedieron en él.
> 6. m. Militar que ha desertado de un ejército y sirve en el enemigo.
> 7. m. C. Rica. Plátano desecado al sol.
> 8. m. pl. Ascendientes o antepasados.
> 9. f. Acción de pasar de una parte a otra.
> 10. f. Acción y efecto de planchar ligeramente.
> 11. f. Acción y efecto de dar un último repaso o retoque a un trabajo cualquiera.
> 12. f. paso geométrico.
> 13. f. Renta suficiente para mantenerse y pasar la vida.
> 14. f. Partida de juego.
> 15. f. Sitio por donde se pasa.
> 16. f. Puntada larga que se da en la ropa al bordarla o zurcirla.
> 17. f. coloq. Mal comportamiento de una persona con otra. Una mala pasada

¿Alguien ve cómo encaja *pasada* en alguna de estas definiciones? Si no, ¿alguien puede dar alguna explicación a esta expresión?

Comment: En esos casos es un sinónimo de "es increíble".

Comment: Posible uso coloquial de la quinta o sesentava definición del verbo pasar? - 5) *Ir más allá de un punto limitado o determinado. Pasar la raya. Pasar el término.* - 60) *Exceder en una calidad o propiedad, o usar de ella con demasía. Pasarse de bueno. Pasarse de cortés.*

Comment: @AlexBcn, completamente de acuerdo. Es como en "Te has pasado tres pueblos" --> Has ido demasiado lejos. O "Se pasa de bueno"--> Es **demasiado** bueno.

Comment: @AlexBcn de acuerdo también. Creo que es una de esas expresiones que no tiene una explicación muy compleja. Si escribes una respuesta con ese argumento, lo daría por bueno ;)

Comment: @AlexBcn parece que esta es la respuesta. Podrías añadirla como tal : )

Comment: En cuanto pille un teclado español :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*¡Qué pasada!* viene de las expresiones

- pasarse de la raya
- pasarse del límite

Viene a decir que algo se sale de la media, del límite establecido. En España se usa en sentido positivo, en otros países como Mexico lo asocian en sentido negativo:

> Ella es una pasada (se pasó de la raya, está mal lo que hizo)

Comment: En España se puede usar con sentido tanto positivo como negativo; el ejemplo de GingerHead (dejando aparte eso de los *pagos*, que tampoco he oído en mi vida) es bueno. Pero lo que apuntas sobre el origen parece bastante razonable.

Comment: Bien visto, quizas es mejor decir: "En españa suele usarse en sentido positivo".

Answer (score 1):

In Spanish language, in general, there are expressions that are copied from other languages like English (ex: **you don't say!** *`¡no me digas!`*) and there are some that are original and never had been copied from a foreign language, for this expression the latter is the case, let's look into that more:

As a first tip, I am sure that you are going to think that the Spanish people are twisted (*we eat green beans with beer as a side serving for lunch*), but "***`¡que pasada!`***" is complimentary and derogatory and yes at the same time (*according to its context!*) ;)

### Here's a complimentary example:

> Por fin encontré tu página web. !Qué pasada! ¡Eres un genio!
>
> *I found your website at last, (WOW), you are a genius!.*

### Here's a derogatory example:

> ¡Qué pasada! me han cobrado cinco mil pavos.
>
> *What a rip off! they've charged me 5,000 euros*

Answer (score 0):

¡Qué pasada! significa "¡Qué exageración!", "¡Qué poca finura!".

> G**anaron el partido de baloncesto contra los azules, por 220 puntos a
>   11 ¡qué pasada!**
>
> *Algunos chistes duros de humor muy negro no son buenos, son una mala
>   pasada.*

Comment: Bienvenido a [spanish.se] y gracias por tu contribución. Nótese que el significado ya lo conozco, lo que estoy buscando es el origen de esta y dónde encaja en la definición de "pasar". Por cierto, puedes usar [edit] para mejorar el formato.